# Оптимизация PHP

Tags: php, оптимизация

Всем привет! У меня есть такой вот код:

```
        $res = array();
            $i2 = 0;
            for($i = 0; $i <10;$i++){
                if($table['users'][$i]['value'] == null){
                    break;
                }
                $res['users'][$i2]['value']=$table['users'][$i]['value'];
                $res['users'][$i2]['user_id']=$table['users'][$i]['user_id'];
                $res['users'][$i2]['name']=$table['users'][$i]['name'];
                $i2++;
            }
            $mesto;
            for($i3 = 0; $i3<count($table['users']);$i3++){
                if($user_id == $table['users'][$i3]['user_id']){
                    $mesto = $i3+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            $res['currentTop'] = $mesto;
            $json = json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
            echo $json;
```

*$table* - Это декодированный json, в table есть массив users, в котором объекты, в каждом по три поля *value,user_id,name*
Примерно JSON выглядит так:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "value": "994954359439",
        "user_id": 2,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }, {
        "value": 99999,
        "user_id": 99999,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }, {
        "value": 99998,
        "user_id": 99998,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }, {
        "value": 99997,
        "user_id": 99997,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }, {
        "value": 99996,
        "user_id": 99996,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }, {
        "value": 99995,
        "user_id": 99995,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }, {
        "value": 99994,
        "user_id": 99994,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }, {
        "value": 99993,
        "user_id": 99993,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }, {
        "value": 99992,
        "user_id": 99992,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }, {
        "value": 99991,
        "user_id": 99991,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }]
}
```

Самих таких объектов может быть 100.000 и более. Выше приведённый код берёт первые 10 первых объектов из массива и по *user_id* ищет индекс объекта, в котором находится этот *user_id*. Если кратко, то код служит для вывода топ 10 игроков и текущее место юзера. Т.е. данный кусок кода будет вызываться довольно много раз за малое количество времени. У меня в компе стоит intel I3-71... и когда я много раз начинаю спамить открытие страницы, то процессор загружается на ~50% (это на 100 000 объектов), если ставить такой код на вдс, то при большом онлайне вдс может не вывозить, отсюда складывается вопрос: как можно всё это оптимизировать? а именно данную функцию:

```
   $mesto;
            for($i3 = 0; $i3<count($table['users']);$i3++){
                if($user_id == $table['users'][$i3]['user_id']){
                    $mesto = $i3+1;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

*P.S.*
Объектами я называю вот это в Json:

```
{
        "value": "994954359439",
        "user_id": 2,
        "name": "Антон Пискорскйи"
    }
```

Comment: Откуда этот `json` берётся? Если из БД то зачем выбирать всех игроков?

Comment: json влить в БД, и работать с ней. Если часто данные запрашиваются, то топ кэшировать. место игрока вытаскивать запросом.

Comment: Json хранится в файле

Comment: А если через бд делать, и вот эти объекты занести в таблицу, далее с помощью SQL уже сортироваь их и выдоватьн, то нагрузка уменьшается?